# базовом классе Engine создал переменную списка ,но работа с этой переменной вызывает ошибку C2027 ,использование неопред типа node в 39,44 ,46 строках

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class node;
class Engine;
class Engine
{
protected:
    int RoundPerSecond;
    string Name;
public:
    static node* first;
    Engine()
    {
        RoundPerSecond = 0;
        Name = "";
    }
    Engine(string Name, int RoundPerSecond)
    {
        this->Name = Name;
        this->RoundPerSecond = RoundPerSecond;
    }
    void EngInit()
    {

    }
    ~Engine()
    {

    }
    void print()
    {

    };
    static void Show()
    {
        node::Show();//C2027
    }
    void Add(Engine* temp)
    {
        if (!first)
            first = new node(temp);//C2027
        else
            first->Add(temp);//C2027
    };
}* listEng;
class ICE:public Engine // Двигатель ДВС
{
    int Cylinders;
    float HorsePower;
public:
    ICE() :Engine()
    {
        Cylinders = 0;
        HorsePower = 0.f;
    }
    ICE(int Cylinders,float HorsePower,string Name,int RoundPerSecond) :Engine(Name,RoundPerSecond)//число цилинров ,лошадинные силы,имя ,оборотов в секунду
    {
        this->Cylinders = Cylinders;
        this->HorsePower = HorsePower;
    }
    ~ICE()
    {
        cout << "\nICE destructor\n";
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << Name << " " << Cylinders << " " << RoundPerSecond << " "<< HorsePower <<" ICE ";
    }
    void Add()
    {
        listEng->Add(this);
    }
    operator Engine* ()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<Engine*>(this);
    }
};
class JetEngine:public Engine //Рeактивный двигатель
{
    float Thrust;
public:
    JetEngine():Engine()
    {
        Thrust = 0.f;
    }
    JetEngine(float Thrust, string Name, int RoundPerSecond) :Engine(Name, RoundPerSecond)// Тяга ,Имя,Число оборотов
    {
        this->Thrust = Thrust;
    }
    ~JetEngine()
    {
        cout << "\njet destructor\n";
    }
    void Add()
    {
        listEng->Add(this);
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << Name << " " << Thrust << " " << RoundPerSecond<< " jet engine ";
    }
    operator Engine* ()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<Engine*>(this);
    }
};
class node
{
    friend Engine;
    Engine* temp;
    node* next, * prev;
    short num = 0;
    static short size;
public:
    node(Engine* temp)
    {
        this->temp = temp;
        next = prev = NULL;
        num++;
        size++;
    }
    node()
    {
        next = prev = NULL;
        num = 0;
        temp = NULL;
        size++;
    }
    ~node()
    {
        next = prev = NULL;
        temp->~Engine();
        size--;
    }
    void Add(Engine* temp)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this->next == NULL)
            {
                node* newone = new node(temp);
                this->next = newone;
                newone->prev = this;
                newone->num += this->num;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                node* pnode = this;
                while (pnode->next != NULL)
                {
                    pnode = pnode->next;
                }
                node* newone = new node(temp);
                newone->prev = pnode;
                pnode->next = newone;
                newone->num += pnode->num;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            throw "\nelement you are trying to add has no adress in memory\n";
        }
    }
    void Init()
    {
        node* pnode = listEng->first;
        pnode->num = 1;
        pnode = pnode->next;
        while (pnode != NULL)
        {
            pnode->num = 1;
            pnode->num += pnode->prev->num;
            pnode = pnode->next;
        }
    }
    void Delete(int& number)
    {
        if (this != NULL)
        {
            node* pnode = this;
            while (pnode != NULL)
            {
                if (pnode->num == number)
                {
                    if (pnode == listEng->first)
                    {
                        listEng->first = pnode->next;
                        listEng->first->prev = NULL;
                        pnode->~node();
                        this->Init();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (pnode->prev)->next = pnode->next;
                        (pnode->next)->prev = pnode->prev;
                        pnode->~node();
                        this->Init();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                pnode = pnode->next;
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "\nlist if empty\n";
    }
    static void Show()
    {
        node* pnode = listEng->first;
        while (pnode != NULL)
        {
            pnode->temp->print();
            cout << " #" << pnode->num << endl;
            pnode = pnode->next;
        }
    }
    static short Size()
    {
        return size;
    }
    Engine* GetElement(int& number)
    {
        if (number < this->size)
        {
            node* pnode = this;
            while (pnode != NULL)
            {
                if (pnode->num == number)
                    return pnode->temp;
                pnode = pnode->next;
            }
        }
        else
            throw "\nthere is no element that number at list\n";
    }
};
short node::size = 0;
node* Engine::first = NULL;
int main()
{
    listEng = new Engine();
    JetEngine VTR(9000.f,"VTR",15000);
    ICE dvs(8, 150, "V5", 3000);
    ICE dvs1(2, 30, "M2", 2500);
    JetEngine VTR1(8400.f, "VTR1", 13000);
    dvs.Add();
    VTR.Add();
    dvs1.Add();
    VTR1.Add();
    Engine::Show();
    int i;
    cout <<node::Size()<<"\nenter number of element which will be deleted ";
    cin >> i;
    listEng->first->Delete(i);
    Engine::Show();
    cout << "enter number of element which will be extract ";
    cin >> i;
    Engine* temp=listEng->first->GetElement(i);
    temp->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: static void Show()
    {
        node::Show();
    }

Comment: first = new node(temp);

Comment: first->Add(temp);

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос то, что написали в комментариях. Или прямо в коде пометьте. Для этого под вопросом есть кнопка ```Править``` А комментарии удалите

Comment: это я понимаю ,исправлю ,спасибо

Comment: тут проблема в другом ,то я уже исправил